# How can I make a website support VIM keybindings?

Tags: javascript, vi

I know lots of websites support VIM-like key binding (gg, G, jkhl),

I want to make my website support them, is there any Javascript project I can use?

cannot find out through Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to see the code you will need to checkout: http://ace.ajax.org/
Another option which is not a js lib (but FF extension) that gives you this functionality: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_key_bindings_for_Firefox

Comment: I'm using Vimium now, what I want is a js library for my website to support hjkl/G/gg key binding...